# Puppet: Ensuring a Specific Configuration Line Exists in the "ssh" Section of /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

Tags: linux, puppet

We have a cluster of nodes whose configuration is maintained by Puppet. Puppet ensures that **sssd** is installed via:

```
service { 'sssd':
   ensure  => running,
   enable  => true,
   require => Package[$libsss_sudo_package],
}
```

However, a default **sssd.conf** is used; I cannot find a modifiable template. A concrete example of a generated **sssd.conf** from a particular node in the cluster is as follows:

```
[domain/example.com]

cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
ipa_domain = example.com
id_provider = ipa
auth_provider = ipa
access_provider = ipa
ipa_hostname = host-1.muskrat.local
chpass_provider = ipa
ipa_server = _srv_, ipa-server.example.com
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ipa/ca.crt
[sssd]
services = nss, sudo, pam, ssh

domains = example.com
[nss]
homedir_substring = /home

[pam]

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]

[pac]

[ifp]
```

Every **sssd.conf** is different because the parameter **ipa_hostname** varies on each host. So, I can't just define an "sssd" module and use a fixed **sssd.conf**.

In Puppet, how may I ensure that a particular line gets added to a particular section of an existing **sssd.conf**?

Specifically, I want to disable hashing of **/var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts** by adding this line to the **[ssh]** section of **sssd.conf**:

```
[ssh]
ssh_hash_known_hosts = false
```

How may I do so in Puppet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need Puppet to know what the correct _ipa_hostname_ is for the host it is running on. Lets make that a variable and call it _$my_ipa_host_.

Second, you need a template (.ebb or .erb) file. Let's call it sssd.erb.
Put your existing sssd.conf file into [module_path]/templates/sssd.erb
Edit sssd.erb so that the ipa_hostname entry looks like this:
`ipa_hostname = <%= @my_ipa_host %>` 

Now, have puppet create the file, using the template instead of the actual file:
`file { '/etc/sssd/sssd.conf': 
 content => template('[module_name]/sssd.erb'), 
 }`
Then, to be sure your sssd.conf file contains the other line, add this to your module:
`ini_settings { 'disable hashing': 
 ensure  => present,
    path    => '/etc/sssd/sssd.conf',
    section => 'ssh',
    setting => 'ssh_hash_known_hosts',
    value   => 'false',
  }`